# My BLED112 dongle doesn't list as a COM port in device manager

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am implementing a project based Bluetooth so I bought a bluetooth dongle BLED112.Normally, when I plug in to PC this dongle, I could see it as COM port in Windows or Ubuntu.But now I cannot see it as COM port.When I plug in to PC, PC detect it as **Mouse HID** not COM port in Windows Device Manager like [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrX6q.jpg).
I looked [Silabs](https://www.silabs.com/wireless/bluetooth/bluegiga-low-energy-legacy-modules/device.bled112) documents and also installed and run a few software [in this site](https://www.silabs.com/wireless/bluetooth/bluegiga-low-energy-legacy-modules/device.bled112) for recovering the dongle.But these are not working.
I found to reflash BLED112 [in this site](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2015/08/06/_how-to_reflash_th-3Bwl).But for reflashing extra hardware named CC debugger is needed.
So is there a way to reflash the dongle without any hardware or what can I do overcome this issue?